# Users with same profile and role cannot view a visualforce

Tags: visualforce, community

I have two partner Users which have same profile and same role but one of this cannot view a visualforce in a page.

[image]

As is the same profile, I discard permissions over profile, in my test 6 users view de visualforce succesfuly, just one user have this problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't that specific but from the sounds of things, it seems that you need to grant Visualforce page access to the user. The simpliest way to do this would be to add this via the Profile (although doing this via a permission set *may* be preferable depending on your use case).

In Salesforce, Apex classes and Visualforce pages need to be assigned to a profile/permission set in order to be used by users.

To do this on the profile, navigate to the profile, search for the 'Enabled Visualforce Page Access' section and then select 'Edit'.

If, as you say in your question, the users definitely are on the same Profile and Visualforce access is enabled on it, I wonder if the user that cannot see the page doesn't have the 'Author Apex' user permission?

[image]

Comment: Yes, the profile already have the permissions over the visualforce since other users with same profile can view the visualforce.  At user level I alredy compared and have same permissions, nothing special, but only one user cannot view the visualforce.